# Duplicate key error! But there is no duplicate data

Tags: git, go, primary-key, timescaledb

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR ERROR #23505 duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tableName_pkey": 
ERROR Error while creating table record =  Record not inserted!:
```

A little background:

My service was working fine on my branch and there was no duplicate key error.
But my service started throwing this duplicated error ever since I merged my code with my colleague.

I have tried to find the mistake but unable to track it.
Every time unique data is being sent to the table but still this error is displayed.

Comment: Can you share the schema of the table, the hypertable and few insert statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and use [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect), [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17267816/6309).

Actually, since you know the error comes from one of the commits from your colleague's merged branch, you could try and merge incrementally that branch (by merging only the first commit of that branch, then the second, and so on), checking each time if those changes introduces the bug you are experiencing.